# How do I make Last Edit timestamp specific to each tab, with multiple tabs to be added in future?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp

**UPDATE:** Got this to work with the following script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

var range = e.range;
var sheet = range.getSheet();
var name = sheet.getName();
var currentDate = new Date();

  //variable
  var startRow = 1;
  
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col === 7 && row === 3 && sheet.getRange(1,14).getValue() == "" && 
     sheet.getName() != "4-Transfer Walkthru" && 
     sheet.getName() != "1-Cover Sheet" && 
     sheet.getName() != "2-Inventory" && 
     sheet.getName() != "3-Template"){
         sheet.getRange(1,14).setValue(currentDate);
       }
  
  else if(row >= startRow){
    
    sheet.getRange(2,14).setValue(currentDate);
       
  }  
}
```

**Original Post:**
I'm attempting to add a "last edited" timestamp to a cell within each tab of a doc that has many tabs, and will continue to have more tabs added/removed. Everything I've found so far either creates a timestamp whenever anything within the entire doc is edited, or it requires listing out each tab name in the script (which is not ideal as the tabs in this doc are ever-changing).

Is there a way to make edit timestamps specific to each tab, without having to list out each tab's name?

Here's what I have so far, which included a timestamp for when the tab is first created (run by any edits made to cell J3), as well as the timestamp that updates across all tabs any time anything is edited in entire doc:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  addTimestamp(e);
  
}


function addTimestamp(e){
  //variable
  var startRow = 1;
  
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col === 7 && row === 3 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,14).getValue() == ""){
         e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,14).setValue(currentDate);
       }
  
  if(row >= startRow && 
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Transfer Walkthru" && 
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Cover Sheet" && 
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Inventory" && 
     e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() != "Template"){
    
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,14).setValue(currentDate);
       
  }
  
}
```

ETA: [Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4cPIqLckUU9y1Zssh7L3AxxOYTsOhrJtHC-XkFfR3Q/edit#gid=1025228618)

Thank you!

Comment: `Is there a way to make edit timestamps specific to each tab, without having to list out each tabs name?` what do you mean here? you want to edit specific tabs based on their name? you want to exclude specific tabs based on their name? You have two options, either include/exclude by name or by position. In other words, what will be the `way/method` you want to identify the tabs that your code will be executed upon edit.

Comment: That question was a direct follow up to this section: *"...or it requires listing out each tab name in the script (which is not ideal as the tabs in this doc are ever-changing)."*

The doc's tabs are ever-changing - with tabs being added and removed fairly often (plus there are a lot of them). I'm looking for a script that will have timestamps specific to each sheet (so an edit on tab #1 does not populate a timestamp on tab #2), without requiring me to update the script to list extra tab names every time a tab is added.

Comment: `so an edit on tab #1 does not populate a timestamp on tab #2` this should not be happening based on your code. You are using the active sheet as the sheet to set the values upon edit. Namely, the time-stamp goes only to the edited sheet and not to other sheets.

Comment: Welp, it's happening ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I should clarify and reiterate - there are 2 timestamps. 1 that only updates once, if N1 is blank, as a "when this section was created" time stamp. That one is working just fine, updating 1 tab only.

The ask is for the 2nd part, that stamps for every edit to a tab. That one for whatever reason updates across the whole sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### `onEdit` allows you to access the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `range` from which you cn deduct the sheet where the edit took place

Then you can implement conditional statements into your code to specify what shall happen depending on which sheet has been edited.

The problem with your code is probably due to `e.source.getActiveSheet()` because the active sheet might not always be the edited sheet.

I recommend you to retrieve the sheet with `e.range.getSheet()` instead.

Sample:

```js
function onEdit(e) {

var range = e.range;
var sheet = range.getSheet();
var name = sheet.getName();
var currentDate = new Date();

  //variable
  var startRow = 1;
  
  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var currentDate = new Date();
  
  if(col === 7 && row === 3 && sheet.getRange(1,14).getValue() == ""){
         sheet.getRange(1,14).setValue(currentDate);
       }
  
  else if(row >= startRow && 
     sheet.getName() != "Transfer Walkthru" && 
     sheet.getName() != "Cover Sheet" && 
     sheet.getName() != "Inventory" && 
     sheet.getName() != "Template"){
    
    sheet.getRange(2,14).setValue(currentDate);
       
  }  
}
```

Comment: Still unable to get it to work correctly (it is still updating every single tab with a timestamp, no matter which tab has an edit). 

I replaced all the `e.source.getActiveSheet()` with `e.range.getSheet()` as suggested, and even copied over the reformatted sample given, and it's still doing the same thing (timestamping all tabs no matter where edit is made).

Comment: I should clarify and reiterate - there are 2 timestamps. 1 that only updates once, if N1 is blank, as a "when this section was created" time stamp. That one is working just fine, updating 1 tab only.

The ask is for the 2nd part, that stamps for every edit to a tab. That one for whatever reason updates across the whole sheet.

Comment: Not sure if I follow you. Can you maybe provide some screenshots or a dummy sheet for visualization purposes?

Comment: Sure!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DNEZKhMVrx0BaYXQxDN9gK2lA_76QVDhNqfhN3sbT3Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I update the code in my answer to give you a sample for the 2nd part too!

Comment: Nice! So, weird thing: The doc I'm using this with has many more tabs than the example doc. It works as expected in the sample doc, but when I transfer it to the actual doc, multiple tabs get updated with any edit. Edits made to tab1 have stopped adding timestamp to, say, tabs5-20, but is still updating across tabs1-4. (It's not always those exact numbers, but as an example). Not sure why the script would work for some but not all tabs.

Comment: Here's an [updated example sheet that looks closer to the final doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E4cPIqLckUU9y1Zssh7L3AxxOYTsOhrJtHC-XkFfR3Q/edit#gid=1025228618)

Extra weird, as it doesn't seem to be happening in this doc either... only on the final sheet. The only difference I can think of, is there are a couple additional scripts on final.

Comment: You should gain an understanding for what is happening in the `if...else` statement. Currently  `if` is working for all tabs, while `else` works for all tabs except the four you specified in the condition - if you have a different spreadsheet with different tab names - you need to adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Right right, I'm not talking about the 4 tabs I *want* it to exclude. I had updated the else section, and that's all good. That's working just fine. The issue is it is still updating multiple tabs.

Comment: Got it to work correctly by moving things around, updated original post. Thank you @ziganotschka !